# Кофе(-)индустрия

Tags: орфография, заимствования, сложные-слова

Как правильно писать: (1) *кофе индустрия*, (2) *кофе-индустрия* или (3) *кофеиндустрия*? Почему?

Написание *индустрия кофе* понятно и не рассматривается.

В (1) *кофе* — несклоняемое прилагательное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Сейчас в языке используются два словосочетания: ***кофейная индустрия и индустрия кофе.***

Например: *Сегодня индустрия кофе переживает небывалый подъем. Как сейчас устроена кофейная индустрия в России?*

2) Сложного слова ***кофе(-)индустрия*** нет, как нет и необходимости в нем. В Интернете можно встретить вариант "кофе индустрия", но это только **тема для поисковика,** который выдает по ней те же сочетания: кофейная индустрия и индустрия кофе.

2) **Если бы слово существовало,** то оно писалось бы **слитно** в соответствии с общими правилами словообразования. Способ образования — чистое сложение, связь основ — **подчинительная**. Как образец — *киноиндустрия*.

**Дефисное** написание не используется, так как это **не сочетание** "приложение + определяемое слово, а **сложное слово.**

Сравнить у Лопатина: Через дефис пишутся: **сочетания с приложениями**, в которых первая часть представляет собой несклоняемое существительное, например: **кафе-автомат, каноэ-одиночка**. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=66#pp66

**Раздельное** написание двух нарицательных существительных *кофе индустрия* (английский вариант) не соответствует правилам.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой материал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=297459

Скорее всего, всё-таки слитно, как и *киноиндустрия*, *агроиндустрия*.

Answer (score 2):

Если задаться целью словообразования от изредка встречающегося сочетания "кофейная индустрия" (вместо обычной "кофейной промышленности"), то получится слово со слитным написанием (по правилу словообразования с сокращением первой части): "*кофеиндустрия*" - которое поисковики предлагают заменить на "фотоиндустрию". Мне тоже такое новшество представляется *ненужным*:  с тем же количеством букв есть более благозвучное и реально употребляемое словосочетание "**индустрия кофе**" (от английского coffee industry).